# Have trailing zero when dealing with money

Tags: java

I need to create a method that returns the total amount of money in dollar notation with two decimal places. Any help would be wonderful. This is what I have so far...

```
private final double QVALUE = 0.25;
private final double DVALUE = 0.10;
private final double NVALUE = 0.05;
private final double PVALUE = 0.01;

public double dollarValue() {
    double amount = (quarters * QVALUE) + (dimes * DVALUE) + 
        (nickels * NVALUE) + (pennies * PVALUE);
    return amount;
}
```

I have provided the values for each coin and the method I need to return a double in. Thanks!

Ex. When I get $1.50 for the total amount of money, it displays as $1.5, I need it to display $1.5 and I do not want to use DecimalFormat because it needs to return a String

Comment: consider this code `System.out.println(String.format("$%.2f", 1.5));`

Comment: Again, it needs to return a value

Comment: Shane, the primitive double value does not have formatting, you will have to format it yourself, as per my comment and @sam answer

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible, because a double does not have any way to represent formatting information. It's just a binary representation of a quantity. Presentation is handled elsewhere, for example using the String.format method suggested several times already.

Comment: I apologize, I understand what you are saying now. I've had very little sleep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "it needs to return a String". Can't you just use `String.format("%.2f", d);`?

Comment: The method needs to return a double, if I use String.format("%.2f", d); then it will be returning a String. You also cannot type cast a double and a String or vice versa

Comment: String.format _can_ take a double. The issue is that Java always removes trailing zeroes. Surely you could just use String.format wherever you're actually presenting the information - your computer doesn't care whether the intended value of your variable is 1.5 or 1.50, because they're technically the same.

Answer (score 3):

May be this is what you want:

```
NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
String s = currencyFormat.format(1.5);
```

Result is `"$1.50"`

Comment: That's still returning a String, which the OP has objected to. Good answer, though. +1